# Hardcoded values are passed as null

Tags: sqlite, symfony

I am doing a To Do app and I am stuck on a weird problem. The variables that are generated and taken from session are correct, but the values I gave are passed as null.

```
public function new(Session $session)
{
    $user=$session->get('user');
    $user=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('Login'=>$user),array());
    $listName='Shopping';
    $content='Eggs';
    $now= new \DateTime();
    dump($user);
    dump($now);

    $todo=new Todo();
    $todo->setUser($user);
    $todo->setList($listName);
    $todo->setContent($content);
    $todo->setAdded($now);
    
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($todo);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash(
        'success',
        'Added it!'
    );

    return $this->render('result.html.twig', []);
}
```

The problem concerns $listName and $content variables.

This is the error I get:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO todo (list, content, details, added, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, "2019-06-12 08:31:41", 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: todo.content

Dumping variables gave their values.

I have no clue why it is passed as null. Anybody have any idea to fix it?

Comment: What types are supposed to be `todo.list` and `todo.content` ?

Comment: Could we have the code of Todo Entity? in a gist maybe

Comment: @Cid List is a string, Content is a text

Comment: @DylanDelobel https://pastebin.com/Fi25HcRq - Todo Entity

Comment: Case sensitive:   $this->Content != $this->content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shown code, you have

```
//       v------ lower case
private $list;
//       v------ lower case
private $content;
```

And then :

```
public function getList(): ?string
{
         //       v------ upper case
    return $this->List;
}

public function setList(string $List): self
{
  //       v------ upper case
    $this->List = $List;

    return $this;
}
public function getContent(): ?string
{
         //       v------ upper case
    return $this->Content;
}

public function setContent(string $Content): self
{
  //       v------ upper case
    $this->Content = $Content;

    return $this;
}
```

They are differents properties. Fix the first letter case in either the property (in example : `private $Content;`) or in the getters/setters (in example : `$this->content = $Content;`)